# Why do people tend to hate the beginning of Black Clover?

Tags: black-clover

After having watched *Black Clover*, I have been listening to their intros 10 times or more and rewatching some scenes again and again, but while scrolling down in the comments I see comments of the form "no one knew black clover can become this great", "the beginning was horrible" and other comments filled with dislike towards the beginning of the show.

What aspects of the anime's beginning caused so many people to dislike it?

Comment: Are you asking why the anime in general was disliked, or why the *beginning* was disliked? The title suggests you're asking the former, but the actual body of your question suggests you're asking the latter.

Comment: Everyone has their own freedom to talk what they want to. If you think the anime good, then it's good. no need to bother other people's opinion. Maybe it's not their favor, so they dislike.

Comment: @F1Krazy Thank you for the specification. Yes, I am asking why people hate the beginning.

Comment: @kit Indeed, everyone has his right to talk what they want, I'm just wondering why _most of the people_ tend to that opinion.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I've proposed an edit to make the question clearer.

Comment: I think this question will be closed as opinion-based.

Comment: @SujalMotagi Ahh, sad.

Answer (score 3):

The closest I can get to answering this in a non-opinion based way is to base it on the opinion of someone quasi-famous, i.e. a reviewer who has discussed Black Clover across its run. To start with, YouTuber Gigguk reviewed Black Clover twice - once in November 2017 shortly after the show began, and once in October 2018. His original video is titled "[Black Clover: The New Problem Child of Shounen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vRLyJxvqX_E)", while the follow-up is titled "[Black Clover Does NOT Suck Anymore.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhWgRovPib8)", so that might give a bit of a hint as to how his opinions shifted in that year (although, spoiler alert, he did already see the potential early on and mostly had an issue with how the show was moving in its first episodes).

Some of the key points from both videos, especially noting the reasons why Black Clover was not received well early on:

- The most recent big shounen shows to have aired just before Black Clover were the second seasons of My Hero Academia and Attack on Titan. These shows are both considered to be highly influential (although AoT season 2 was not necessarily as well received as the first season), and people felt they took the genre forward with some amount of innovation and story telling.
- The early set-up of Black Clover seemed to be highly generic in terms of shounen - spiky-haired protagonist with no power but big dreams discovers he actually has the most amazing power ever, joins a group of misfits and deals with a series of increasing threats by getting more powerful himself. As Gigguk points out in his second video, the show never really gets more original (although from what I saw of the end of the first big arc, it did try to do a bit more with the story later on) - but it does build a certain amount of self-awareness in its derivativeness and goes all-in on using all of the big shounen tropes.
- The show felt low-effort in various ways - characters didn't have the detailed backstories of, say, My Hero Academia characters; the animation quality was much lower than those other shows; and since every episode started with not just a recap of the previous episode/s (often trying to explain everything that was going on, not just the parts that would make it easier to follow this episode), but a recap of the history of the world, you wind up with only about 15 minutes of "new" content in a 25 minute show.
- The show moved very slowly - as Gigguk points out, a typical episode of a shounen anime will adapt about 2 chapters of the manga. The first 6 episodes of Black Clover adapted 4 chapters of the manga, meaning that it was stalling for time heavily at a point where it was supposed to be building up expectations.
- Asta had no lines that were spoken at a volume below a scream. As the main character, this was incredibly grating for a lot of people.